# Swift 4 - Alamofire - How to disable cache on request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have this Alamofire request like so:

```
func loginUser(_ username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)
    {

        let user = username

        let password = password

        let url = webservice

        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .none)

        let headers = ["Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON {
                (response) in

                print(response.result)

                switch response.result {

                case .success:
                    if let value = response.result.value {

                        completion(true)

                    }else{

                        print("There is error in the server response")

                        completion(false)
                    }

                case .failure (let error):

                    print("The NTLM request error is: ", error.localizedDescription)

                    completion(false)

                }

            }

    }
```

My problem with it is it works when I use invalid credentials after using valid credentials, instead of spitting out an error. I have been told this maybe a caching issue, so my question is how do I disable cache for this request?

I have tried adding this to the top of my request:

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

But that didn't work

I also saw this:

```
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
```

But I have no idea where to apply it.

Please help!

UPDATE

I have tried the following:

```
func loginUser(_ username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)
    {

        let user = username

        let password = password

        let url = webservice

        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .none)

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

        urlRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        urlRequest.httpMethod = "get"

        urlRequest.setValue("application/json;odata=verbose", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")

        urlRequest.setValue("application/json;odata=verbose", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        Alamofire.request(urlRequest).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON {
                (response) in

                switch response.result {

                case .success:
                    if let value = response.result.value {


                       completion(true)

                    }else{

                        print("There is error in the server response")

                        completion(false)
                    }

                case .failure (let error):

                    print("The NTLM request error is: ", error.localizedDescription)

                    completion(false)

                }

            }

    }
```

But that did not work, same result.

Answer (score 5):

You can instantiate a `Alamofire.SessionManager` with a specific `URLSessionConfiguration`. In the configuration you can set the cachePolicy. This could look like this:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy // or whatever you want
configuration.urlCache = nil
let mySessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

and then use it as follows:

`mySessionManager.request(urlRequest)`....

Note that you have to use `mySessionManager` to do requests instead of using `Alamofire.request` if you follow this.

To make a request using mySessionManager it is basically the same instead of `Alamofire.request(urlRequest)`... you use `mySessionManager.request(urlRequest)`...

Comment: How would I do a mySessionManager request?

Comment: no member 'mySessionManager' do I have to define it somewhere?

Comment: @user979331 I declared it as property of the class first. I edited again i hope its clearer now.

Comment: I tried the mySessionManager and when I do it goes right into the .failure case saying The NTLM request error is:  cancelled

Comment: Yea no matter what I do, it fails.